# Error compiling sass in vscode with DartJS Sass Compiler extension

Tags: sass, bulma

I'm trying to implement a project using Bulma, but I'm hitting the following error when the extension tries to compile the sass files:

```
Error: Run: Cwd: /Users/.../Projects/.... Exec: node-modules/.bin/sass 
`stylesheets/styles.scss:stylesheets/styles.css did not launch correctly. pid is null / undefined - undefined`
```

I've not been able to find any solution or reference to this by googling, so I'd be really grateful if someone can give me a tip.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer helped me with the solution. See [here](https://github.com/codelios/vscode-dartsass/issues/18)